Error when trying to generate symmetric key with yubihsm
Here's the translation of your question into English:
Hello everyone, I’m having trouble creating symmetric keys using pkcs11js.
What I think might be happening is that I’m missing some attribute in the TEMPLATE that I pass to the C_GenerateKeyAsync function, or that the mechanism I’m passing to the function is not entirely correct.
I’ve been searching through the pkcs11js documentation and couldn’t find anything that helps solve the problem, and the same goes for the YubiHSM2 documentation.
The issue occurs when I try to create a symmetric key using the C_GenerateKeyAsync method. The error I’m getting is as follows:
errorData: {
        name: 'Pkcs11Error',
        message: 'CKR_FUNCTION_FAILED',
        stackTrace: 'Pkcs11Error: CKR_FUNCTION_FAILED\n' +
          '    at prepareError (/opt/c-cipher/node_modules/pkcs11js/index.js:58:12)\n' +
          '    at /opt/c-cipher/node_modules/pkcs11js/index.js:94:19'
      },

And the YubiHSM2 logs are as follows:
[LIB - ERR 12:10:14.736362] yubihsm.c:2248 (generate_key): Failed to send GENERATE SYMMETRIC KEY command: Invalid command
[P11 - ERR 12:10:14.736387] yubihsm_pkcs11.c:5142 (C_GenerateKey): Failed generating symmetric key

This is my code:
async generateSymmetricKeyService(_symmetric) {
    let SESSION;
    let SESSION_ACTIVE = false;
    let SLOT;
    try {
      pkcs11Lib.C_Initialize({
        library: CC_OWN_CONST.LIB_PATH,
      });

      //? Get the list of slots and select one
      const SLOTS = pkcs11Lib.C_GetSlotList(true);
      SLOT = SLOTS[0];
      if (!SLOT) throw new ErrorUtilClass(__filename, 'TCG_DYT', 'Slot not available').server();

      //? Open a session
      SESSION = pkcs11Lib.C_OpenSession(SLOT, pkcs11js.CKF_SERIAL_SESSION | pkcs11js.CKF_RW_SESSION);
      pkcs11Lib.C_Login(SESSION, pkcs11js.CKU_USER, CC_OWN_CONST.CREDENTIAL.PASSWORD);
      SESSION_ACTIVE = true;

      //? Define the template for the symmetric key
      const TEMPLATE =  [
      { type: pkcs11js.CKA_CLASS, value: pkcs11js.CKO_SECRET_KEY },
      { type: pkcs11js.CKA_TOKEN, value: true },
      { type: pkcs11js.CKA_KEY_TYPE, value: pkcs11js.CKK_AES },
      { type: pkcs11js.CKA_LABEL, value: _symmetric.labelKey },
      { type: pkcs11js.CKA_VALUE_LEN, value: _symmetric.sizeKey },
      { type: pkcs11js.CKA_ENCRYPT, value: true },
      { type: pkcs11js.CKA_EXTRACTABLE, value: true }
     ];
     let KEY;

       KEY = await pkcs11Lib.C_GenerateKeyAsync(SESSION,{ mechanism: pkcs11js.CKM_AES_KEY_GEN }, TEMPLATE).catch((_error) => {
        throw new ErrorUtilClass(__filename, 'TCG_DYT', _error).server();
      });

      return KEY;
    } catch (_error) {
      throw !_error.errorType ? new ErrorUtilClass(__filename, 'TCG_DYT', _error).server() : _error;
    } finally {
      if (SESSION_ACTIVE) {
        pkcs11Lib.C_Logout(SESSION);
        pkcs11Lib.C_CloseSession(SESSION);
      }
      pkcs11Lib.C_Finalize();
    }
  },

I’ve tried changing the template attributes and also adding parameters to the mechanism, but I haven’t been able to find the solution.

In my experience, all HSM's do not support key extraction as a default behavior. Some HSM's strictly don't allow, and some HSM's do, by changing some kind of configuration (for which the HSM will warn you that it is an insecure setting). Try setting CKA_EXTRACTABLE to false and see if that works.
